# How to hash a single char to a relatively small prime in C++?

Tags: c++, hash, hashtable

I am interested in hashing the alphabet letters to different prime numbers which are relatively small. For example,  `a->2,b->3, c->5, d->7, ...`. Since I will be multiplying/dividing hashes of several characters.

I tried `std::hash`, however, it hashes characters to very large integers and it causes overflows if I multiply/divide, is there an easier way to do this?

One possible way I though of is to use the Sieve of Eratosthenes to generate the first bunch of primes then use a `std::unordered_map` to store `char,int` pairs. **However, is there any ready made hashing function in the standard library that would suit my needs?**

Comment: Yes, `std::map<key, value>`

Comment: @Kyle Khalaf I am not sure what you mean. How would I use ``std::map`` as a hashing function?

Comment: My main problem is actually generating the corresponding key. Each value should be 1) relatively small and 2) prime.

Comment: You will do something like `int main ()
{
  std::map<char,int> MyMap;

  MyMap['a']=2;
  MyMap['b']=3;
  MyMap['c']=4;
  MyMap['d']=7;
  // ...

}` where `a` (or any char) can't exist twice

Comment: @KyleKhalaf I understand that, however, I don't want to generate the 26 prime numbers manually. I am hoping there is a hashing function out there (such as std::hash) where hash('a')=2, hash('b')=3, hash('c')=5 so that I can assign the values automatically rather than writing it on 26 different lines

Comment: The result of `hash` is not necessarily a prime number. If the only problem you have with `hash` is that the numbers are large, do you need them to be primes at all?

Comment: @anatolyg If the numbers generated have a small probability of being the same, then being prime is not an issue. However, the numbers must be smaller than what ``hash`` gives.

Answer (score 6):

I would just store the first 26 primes in a `std::vector` called `primes`, and then if you have character `c`, simply access the correct prime using `primes[c-'a']`.

Comment: I understand. I am just asking if there is any hashing function in the standard library that hashes automatically to small prime numbers, rather than me actually implementing the entire hashing function

Comment: @AspiringMat: No, because that's not what hash functions do. And I don't know of anything in the C++ standard library that deals with primes, except maybe the RNGs.

Comment: @MooingDuck Thank you, that was just basically my question. I wanted a built in function that hashes a character to a prime automatically which is why I ask the question.

Comment: @AspiringMat You seem to somewhat misuse the work 'hash'. By definition, hashing function is a function which takes an input of arbitary length and produces an output of fixed length out of it. Your function receives input of fixed length, thus it's not a hash.